# openUDID using deprecated UDID

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm looking at using [openUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) inside my app for registration purposes.

However its still using the UDID number apple issues and so I was just reading though the .m file and came across this:

```
// One day, this may no longer be allowed in iOS. When that is, just comment this line out.
    //
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE    
    if([UIDevice instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(uniqueIdentifier)]){
        _openUDID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
    }

#endif

    // Take this opportunity to give the simulator a proper UDID (i.e. nullify UDID and create an OpenUDID)
    //
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    _openUDID = nil;
#endif

    // Next we try to use an alternative method which uses the host name, process ID, and a time stamp
    // We then hash it with md5 to get 32 bytes, and then add 4 extra random bytes
    // Collision is possible of course, but unlikely and suitable for most industry needs (e.g.. aggregate tracking)
    //
```

However I'm not sure exactly what line to comment out so that it used the alternative method which uses the host name, process ID, and a time stamp

Comment: now, the lines are commented. happy to use~ https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  would comment out the 3 lines of code in the `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` block

Answer (score 0):

You can "comment" out the line with `uniqueIdentifier` in it by prefixing that line using double slash comment.... or you can change the `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE` line to `#if 0`, which means that block of code will never get called at all.

And then the alternative code will get used instead.

The way the code is currently written, it seems pretty safe to me to just leave it as is.  Once Apple does completely do away with the `uniqueIdentifier` method, the `instancesRespondToSelector` call will properly fail and the alternative code will get used automatically.

Comment: It is only safe if Apple completely removes it. If they decide to return a DEADBEEF uuid or something, it would create problems.

Comment: cmon... do you really think they'd return a 0XDEADBEEF uuid?

Comment: well... no, but maybe they would return a string of 32 0's or something else. They probably wouldn't, but to make assumptions would not be wise.

Comment: @coneybeare: They wouldn't do that, because it would break the contract specified in the method's documentation. Even if they deprecate something in the API, the documentation for it still exists on the Web and the implementation of the method SHOULD conform to the contract they themselves lay out for it. If they want to fully deprecate it, they should remove the implementation altogether (so we get nice errors, which we can easily notice and correct) rather than breaking contract and causing innumerable production systems' analytics/account systems to be flooded with useless/incorrect data.

Comment: (but yes, you're right, we can't assume Apple will NOT do something as stupid as that)